# How to get base 64 from cornerstone

Tags: ohif

In OHIF I need to get base 64 value from cornerstone.because I need to pass the jpeg/png to a api for some prediction task in python flask.

Answer (score 1):

OHIF uses Cornerstone.js to render the image to a canvas. If you only need the rendered pixel values, you can use the Canvas API's [`toDataUrl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL). If you need the underlying / original pixel data, you can use the underlying cornerstone image's [`getPixelData`](https://docs.cornerstonejs.org/api#image) method.